# Nash Equilibrium of a three player game involving three strategies.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I do not see any dominated strategies which can be eliminated. I have tried all points individually to see if they satisfy pure strategy nash equilibrium conditions, none of them do. To find a mixed nash strategy equilibrium, I don't understand how to form the equations.
Any hints(short answers) or ideas would also suffice.

[Three Player Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1eA9.png)